# Linking to a custom .a from multiple objects

Tags: linux, linker, ld

In our build system, we generate multiple .so files (foo.so, bar.so, ...) that are loaded during runtime by the main executable (biz). So the .so files are linked separately.

We also have our own util.a static library, that has some utility functions and global data.

The problem comes when some of the .so want to use util.a data/function, but we can't link each .so to util.a. It's because of the data section: global data must be unique in the program address space. If more than one .so is linked to util.a and has a copy of the data, the program behavior will be very surprising but hard to debug.

We can't link executable (biz) to util.a either. The linker will not put everything to the target, since biz doesn't reference the functions on behalf of .so.

Of course, unless linking util.a with -Wl,-whole-archive. But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Either whole-archive, or make all global data `static`, so each one who using it will have unique dataset.

Comment: What's this surprising behavior when you statically link `.a` to your `.so`s? and why is it hard to debug?

Comment: @HAL Two copies of global data defined in .a, with the same symbol, will change the behavior of program and confuse the debugger.

Comment: @keltar How portable is -Wl,-whole-archive? How to assert all global data is static, and not introduced by mistake in the future?

Comment: @FamZheng behaviour of whole-archive is well-defined, but I'm not sure every possible linker supports that. Better integrate this library directly into program source, but it could raise problems if compiling with `-fvisibility=hidden`.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: consider making util.a a dynamic library util.so.

Solution 2: don't let the linker export any symbols exported by util.a. When using gcc you can achieve this for example by using `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`:

```
int __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) helperfunc(void *p);
```

You can use `objdump` to check which symbols are exported.

Answer (score 0):

To answer myself's question, the eventual solution was like:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2014-09/msg00099.html

TL;DR: Search for all the interesting symbols (that you want to pull from archives) inside the .so objects with `nm (1)`, and inject into the compiling command line with `-Wl,-u,$SYMBOL`. Note that the `-Wl,-u,$SYMBOL` arguments need to come before archive names in the command line, so the linker knows that it needs to link them.